# Ruby on Rails - syntax issues causing me to eventually have nullPointerExceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

from this line:

```
user = User.any_of({:user_name => login},{:email => login}).first   #.and(:encrypted_password => nil).first
```

I am new to Ruby so I am still trying to get the hang of the syntax.  Is there something particularly incorrect or error prone that would cause me to have the object nil[] error?

Also the following line is creating the same error even if I try it without the .downcase

```
login = (params[:user][:login]).downcase
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it the User variable there that is not initiated and is throwing the error?

Comment: I got the any_of from an example... I am not sure what it does here to be honest...same with the .first at the end of that line :)...clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'll take a guess that .first returns a first item in collection. If your any_of condition doesn't return matches, it'll throw an exception (again, guess.. based on LINQ)

Comment: @Eugene makes sense...I tried to remove the .first but it didn't help too much. Read some examples and people are mentioning partials as a solution...not sure yet...researching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in login = (params[:user][:login]).downcase 
if you will pass wrong params aka {:not_user => {}} he will try to get get :login value from null hash because there is not :user hash.

So first thing is to check params from your form. I bet it is problem with them, check

```
log/development.log
```

You will see what is sent to the controller, or just simply put at top of action

```
raise params.inspect
```

Thats fastest way to find our what is happening with params.

Correct params for you should look like this

```
{:user => {:login => "user login ble ble", :password => "ple ple"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby dev.. but I think it tries to tell you that .first expects an array, and any_of returns something else.